# Access paths to nested views in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The rake routes is as follows:
[image]

I want to redirect to the `index` of attachments once a new user has been created.

Currently this is what I am trying:
`users_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to user_attachments_path(@user)
  end
```

`index.html.erb` for `attachments`

```
<% @user.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= attachment.name %></td>
    <td><%= attachment.format %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Download', download_user_attachment_path(attachment), :method => :get %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', user_attachments_path(attachment),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I get the following after I enter details for new user:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
How do I access correct paths to access nested attributes/views?

Comment: Did you migrate the record ?

Comment: @Elyasin I did not add `user_id` to the `attachments` table. Adding that has solved this roadblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to the routes...

The `user_id` is missing in the `attachments` table.

`rails generate migration add_users_id_to_attachments user_id:integer`

and

`rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ahh! Thanks a ton. Could you direct me to some resource regarding Rails 4 that is easy to comprehend? I find the rails guide very difficult to navigate in finding tips like these.

Comment: I don´t know your level of experience, but I always recommend this [book/tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) for beginners. This tutorial was my first contact with rails... I prefer to follow tutorials instead of reading guides...